# Unauthorized access to a server over ssh when client-server connection is ssh-key based

Tags: networking, ssh, security, port-forwarding

Specifically as it pertains to opening up the server from a LAN/WLAN to the internet via port-forwarding.

I'm new to networking. I'd like to access a home server from outside my LAN/WLAN via port-forwarding. I understand you can brute-force attack a server over the internet, if the authentication method is password-based.

I have set up a client-server ssh key pair between my server and the only client I plan on using to connect to my server, and have disabled password authentication on my server. Is accessing the server from a computer that does not have the private key possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, its never *impossible* to access any service, since there are always vulnerabilities. But considering your options for authenticating it is still the best way to go.
Since authenticating with a private key is also based on knowing/having something like a mechanism involving a password your key could, in theory, be bruteforced.
In reality, this is unlikely so I would stick with this authentication method and spend your efforts on securing your key (ie using a password-protected key) on the client.

Comment: This is what I suspected. Thanks for the insight.